# How to stop images moving around on hover?

Tags: html, css

Hi i have made a list of images with transitions upon hover, but as i hover over one the other move all over the place. I though giving them absolute positioning would work but it didnt, so how do i get it so the images dont go all over the place. Thanks.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css">
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="container">
            <img class="pic" src="Chrysanthemum.jpg"/>
            <img src="Desert.jpg"/>
            <img src="Hydrangeas.jpg"/>
            <img src="Jellyfish.jpg"/>
            <img src="Koala.jpg" />
            <img src="Lighthouse.jpg"/>
            <img src="Penguins.jpg"/>
            <img src="Tulips.jpg"/>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
body {       
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}

.container {
    background-color:#c1c1c1;
    height:400px;
    text-align:center;
}

div img {
    height:100px;
    position:relative;
    width:150px;
    top:50%;
    margin-top:-50px;
    transform:skew(30deg);
    transform:rotate(30deg);
    opacity:0.7;
    transition:all 1s ease;
}

img:hover {
    height:400px;
    width:600px;
    transform:skew(0deg);
    transform:rotate(0deg);
    opacity:1;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Fiddle Here,
http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=iM1y1m1vNv

Comment: I believe that you should use `float` for this.

Comment: That is true, doesnt seem to solve my problem though?

Comment: Can you build a fiddle for this?

Comment: "I though giving them absolute positioning would work but it didnt" could you demonstrate it not working with absolute positioning?

Comment: just creating a fiddle now, how can i share it?

Comment: @Jack just edit your original post or post the link here. There's a save button top left-ish and it'll update your url.

Comment: You can't share or update jsfiddles right now, jsfiddle was down earlier and it seems they removed the save option at the moment. They were being spammed according to their twitter post: https://twitter.com/jsfiddle

Comment: Yes i thought i couldnt see the share button like i did the other day!

Comment: Link the images if possible in your jsfiddle. I think the issue is your container's height is set at 400px and your images are going beyond its dimensions. But I could be wrong, it's hard to tell when the images aren't linked

Comment: Image of the codes or the rendering?

Comment: Adding `float: left;` to your `div img` class makes everything much smoother, however it still glitches out when a screen edge is encountered.

Comment: @Jack `position: absolute` for the `imgs`s will do the trick. You need to do a bit more to adjust. Check my answer.

Comment: That looks good anis, is there anyway that when an image is hovered, it displays bigger in the middle of the container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/aniskhan001/03ahadu4/)** here

You need to set `position: absolute;` to the `img`s and **cumulative `margin-left`** for each imgs seperately. Since this is not possible using CSS you need to use JavaScript to achieve that.

I have used **jQuery** in my example.

```
total = $('.pic').siblings();
len = total.length;
value = 0;
offset = 80;
for (var i = 0; i <= len; i++) {
    $(total[i]).css('margin-left', value + offset + 'px');
    value += offset;
}
```

You can see there's an `offset` value to increase each `imgs`s `margin-left` dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Surround each image in its own container, and set the position of the images to be absolute. Set the size of the container to be equal to the size of the unhovered image. Use whatever layout means you need to in order to get the containers into the position you want.

As in:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner-container">
      <img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png"/>
  </div>
  <div class="inner-container">
      <img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png"/>
  </div>
  <div class="inner-container">
      <img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png"/>
  </div>
  <div class="inner-container">
      <img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

And:

```
.container {
    background-color:#c1c1c1;
    height:400px;
    text-align:center;    
}

.inner-container {
    height:100px;
    width:150px;
}

div img {
    position:absolute;
    height:100px;
    width:150px;
    transform:skew(30deg);
    transform:rotate(30deg);
    opacity:0.7;
    transition:all 1s ease;
}

img:hover {
    position:absolute;
    height:400px;
    width:600px;
    transform:skew(0deg);
    transform:rotate(0deg);
    opacity:1;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see someone else has already answered, I thought I would add this anyway as it brings a different approach and includes the rotation like you initially had.

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ctwheels/bw4z6949/

*HTML*

```
<body>
    <div id="me" class="container">
        <div class="table">
            <div class="tr">
                <div class="td">
                    <img class="pic" src="http://cdn.theanimals.pics/pictures/www.flashdance.co.uk/images/Webimages/Pets/W_PET1441041.jpg" />
                </div>
                <div class="td">
                    <img class="pic" src="http://www.photosjunction.com/contents/member/animals/photos/rabbit-picture-ed347.jpg" />
                </div>
                <div class="td">
                    <img class="pic" src="http://www.breederretriever.com/photopost/data/534/DSC00040.JPG" />
                </div>
                <div class="td">
                    <img class="pic" src="http://explosionhub.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/Cat-cats-2533807-1000-800.jpg" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="tr">
                <div class="td">
                    <img class="pic" src="http://cdn.theanimals.pics/pictures/upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/75/American_Red_Fox.jpg" />
                </div>
                <div class="td">
                    <img class="pic" src="http://www.breederretriever.com/photopost/data/587/dalmatian_pup_3.JPG" />
                </div>
                <div class="td">
                    <img class="pic" src="http://www.expatads.com/adpics/-female-pug-puppy-5165b0c0271a4063038f.jpg" />
                </div>
                <div class="td">
                    <img class="pic" src="http://www.singingheartsfarm.com/news/ckeditor/filemanager/userfiles/Prince%20Momentus%20SF%2012-5-12_8934.jpg" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="hoveroutDestroyClone"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

*CSS*

```
body {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
.container {
    background-color:#c1c1c1;
    height:400px;
    text-align:center;
}
.table {
    display:table;
    border-spacing:0px;
    border-collapse:separate;
    padding:15px;
    padding-left:15px;
    padding-top:30px;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-left:auto;
}
.tr {
    display:table-row;
}
.td {
    padding:2px;
    display:inline-block;
}
/*Change these values to reduce or increase spacing bbetween divs/images*/

/*Horizontal spacing*/
 .tr .td:not(:first-of-type) {
    margin-left:-45px;
}
/*Vertical spacing*/
 .tr:not(:first-of-type) .td {
    margin-top:30px;
}
.td img {
    height:100px;
    width:150px;
    opacity:0.7;
    transform:rotate(30deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(30deg);
    /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform:rotate(30deg);
    /* Opera, Chrome, and Safari */
}
.myClass {
    position:absolute;
    height:100px;
    width:150px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.hoveroutDestroyClone {
    /*Invisible div that determines when the mouse is "hovering" the inflated image*/
}
/*Change this for duration of rotation in effect - Note: For flow, change the value of the variable "myDuration" in js to the same length*/
 .rotateMeIn {
    animation:rotateIn 1s;
    -webkit-animation:rotateIn 1s;
}
/*Rotation effects*/
 @keyframes rotateIn {
    from {
        transform:rotate(30deg);
        -ms-transform:rotate(30deg);
        -webkit-transform:rotate(30deg);
    }
    to {
        transform:rotate(0deg);
        -ms-transform:rotate(0deg);
        -webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotateIn {
    from {
        transform:rotate(30deg);
        -ms-transform:rotate(30deg);
        -webkit-transform:rotate(30deg);
    }
    to {
        transform:rotate(0deg);
        -ms-transform:rotate(0deg);
        -webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);
    }
}
/*Change this for duration of rotation in effect - Note: For flow, change the value of the variable "myDuration" in js to the same length*/
 .rotateMeOut {
    animation:rotateOut 1s;
    -webkit-animation:rotateOut 1s;
}
/*Rotation effects*/
 @keyframes rotateOut {
    from {
        transform:rotate(0deg);
        -ms-transform:rotate(0deg);
        -webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
        transform:rotate(30deg);
        -ms-transform:rotate(30deg);
        -webkit-transform:rotate(30deg);
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotateOut {
    from {
        transform:rotate(0deg);
        -ms-transform:rotate(0deg);
        -webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
        transform:rotate(30deg);
        -ms-transform:rotate(30deg);
        -webkit-transform:rotate(30deg);
    }
}
```

*JS*

```
$(".pic").mouseover(

function () {

    $(".hoveroutDestroyClone").trigger("mouseleave");
    $(".hoveroutDestroyClone")
        .css({
        width: 0 + "px",
        height: 0 + "px",
        position: "absolute",
        left: 0 + "px",
        top: 0 + "px",
            "z-index": -1000
    });
    var myClone = $(this).clone();
    var leftTablePadding = parseInt($(".table").css("padding-left"), 10);

    var topTablePadding = parseInt($(".table").css("padding-top"), 10);
    var leftOffset = $(this).offset().left;
    var documentWidth = $(document).width() / 2;
    var topOffset = $(this).offset().top;
    var myHeight = 400;
    var myWidth = 600;
    var myDuration = 1000;
    $(this).css("opacity", 0);
    $(myClone)
        .appendTo(".container")
        .removeClass("pic")
        .addClass("myClass")
        .addClass("rotateMeIn")
        .css({
        left: leftOffset + leftTablePadding + "px",
        top: topOffset + topTablePadding + "px"
    })
        .animate({
        width: myWidth + "px",
        height: myHeight + "px",
        left: documentWidth - myWidth / 2 + "px", //0 + "px",
        top: 0 + "px",
        opacity: 1
    },
    myDuration,

    function () {
        $(".hoveroutDestroyClone")
            .css({
            width: $(myClone).width() + "px",
            height: $(myClone).height() + "px",
            position: "absolute",
            left: $(myClone).offset().left + "px",
            top: $(myClone).offset().top + "px",
                "z-index": 1000
        });
    });
});

$(".hoveroutDestroyClone").on("mouseleave",

function () {
    var myDuration = 1000;
    $(".myClass")
        .addClass("rotateMeOut")
        .animate({
        width: 0 + "px",
        height: 0 + "px",
        left: 0 + "px",
        top: 0 + "px",
        opacity: 0
    }, myDuration, function () {
        $(".rotateMeOut").remove();
        $(".hoveroutDestroyClone")
            .css({
            width: 0 + "px",
            height: 0 + "px",
            position: "absolute",
            left: 0 + "px",
            top: 0 + "px",
                "z-index": -1000
        });
        $(".pic")
            .animate({
            opacity: 0.7
        }, 500);
    });
});
```